# Enable disable jquery script onclick event

Tags: jquery

I have table with td onclick event

```
<td id="ab2" onclick="popup('test')">Link</td>
```

I have disable onclick by calling

```
 $(#ab2").prop("onclick", null);
```

Now i want to enable this link again when some one clicks on enable link below

```
<a href="#">Enable</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do??

Comment: @ Milind Anantwar onbody onload i have disable onclick now again one more link is there enable if anybody clicks on it onclick event will get enabled

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
$("#ab2").unbind("click");

$( "#ab2" ).bind( "click", function() {
  alert( "User clicked" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and **[off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** in jQuery they work for it

**for enable**

```
$(#ab2").on("click");
```

**for disble**

```
$(#ab2").off("click");
```